# C# Code Analysis: static methods that are never used

Tags: c#, static-code-analysis

DAL Project contains a lot of public static method. After some period of development some of them are not used anymore.

Could any one suggest the tool or way to detect the list of methods that are not used by other projects.

**UPDATE**

Found the *Nitriq* tool. It helps to run queries looks like LINQ throught the code.

The **method.CalledBy.Count == 0** mean houw much is this method used by others in current Nitriq's project (analyzed Assembly)

```
var results = 
from method in Methods 
where method.IsStatic && method.IsPublic && method.CalledBy.Count == 0 
    && !method.FullName.Contains("get_") 
    && !method.FullName.Contains("set_") 
    && method.FullName.Contains(".DAL.")
select new { method.MethodId, method.FullName, method.Name, method.Cyclomatic,
method.PhysicalLineCount, Usega = method.CalledBy.Count, method.ParameterCount };
Warn(results, 0);
```

Comment: Highlight the method name, right click `find all references`? Though I'm sure there's probably a purpose built tool out there to do it

Comment: Why are static methods special? I would think one would be interested in any method or field that is never used.

Comment: For Java, at least Eclipse will give a compile-time warning for an un-used method, I believe. Won't Visual Studio do the same?

Comment: If the method is public then how do you know that no one is using it?

Comment: @EricLippert - that is the question. find usage of the method in libraries. I Have found the  Nitriq tool it analyse the libs run banch of predefined rules. User can write his own rules:
var results = 
from method in Methods 
where method.IsStatic && method.IsPublic && method.CalledBy.Count == 0
    && !method.FullName.Contains("get_")
    && !method.FullName.Contains("set_")
    && method.FullName.Contains(".DAL.")
select new { method.MethodId, method.FullName, method.Name, method.Cyclomatic,
method.PhysicalLineCount, Usega = method.CalledBy.Count, method.ParameterCount };
Warn(results, 0);